# php array match within a two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

for example, I have a array:

```
$objects = ['car', 'cat', 'dog', 'Peter'];
```

and another:

```
$types = [
    'man' => ['Peter', 'John','...'],
    'animal' => ['pig', 'cat', 'dog', '...'],
    'vehicle' => ['bus', 'car', '...']
];
```

and my goal is get an array like:

```
$result = [
    'man' => ['Peter'],
    'animal' => ['cat', 'dog'],
    'vehicle' => ['car']
]
```

what is the most efficient way to search within an array, in my current work, I use two foreach loop to search but figured it's too slow, I have about thousands of elements in my array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `array_intersect`:

```
foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
  $result[$key] = array_intersect($type, $objects);
}
```

Comment: But I think add an array_values maybe more fit:`array_values(array_intersect($type, $objects));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$objects = ['car', 'cat', 'dog', 'Peter'];

$types = [
    'man' => ['Peter', 'John'],
    'animal' => ['pig', 'cat', 'dog'],
    'vehicle' => ['bus', 'car']
];

foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
  $result[$key] = array_intersect($type, $objects);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);





Array
(
    [man] => Array
        (
            [0] => Peter
        )

    [animal] => Array
        (
            [1] => cat
            [2] => dog
        )

    [vehicle] => Array
        (
            [1] => car
        )

)
```